# VSCode で Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb) を python スクリプトで出力するエクスポートができない

Tags: python, vscode, jupyter-notebook

VSCode を使用して Jupyter Notebook ファイル (.ipynb) を開いています．
拡張機能として VSCode の Jupyter を使用しています．

作成した Jupyter Notebook のファイルを python スクリプトとして出力したいのですが，エクスポートで python script を選択すると，以下のようなエラーメッセージが出てきて，スクリプトが出力されません．

もし，何かわかることがあれば回答お願いいたします．

```
Info 2021-07-12 17:24:58: Cached data exists getEnvironmentVariables, <No Resource>
Info 2021-07-12 17:24:58: Process Execution: > /usr/bin/python3 -m jupyter nbconvert --version
> /usr/bin/python3 -m jupyter nbconvert --version
Info 2021-07-12 17:24:58: Process Execution: > /usr/bin/python3 -m jupyter nbconvert --version
> /usr/bin/python3 -m jupyter nbconvert --version
Error 2021-07-12 17:24:58: Export failed [i [Error]: Error executing Jupyter command 'nbconvert': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1013163132/out/client/extension.js:24:247448)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)] {
  category: 'unknown'
}
```

Comment: Jupyterはどの様にインストールしたんでしょう？ こちらでは Anaconda3インストールしていて, Anaconda側の Python ＆ Jupyter ＆ nbconvert が動きます。… (Jupyter-server 側に nbconvert 入ってるはずなので)

Comment: Jupyter は，pip3 を使って jupyter モジュールをインストールしています．それが原因かもしれませんね...

Comment: `pip3 list` あるいは `pip list` などで `nbconvert` が入ってるかどうか … 入っていないだけならインストールすれば動きそうな？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！ `nbconvert` はインストールしているんですよね...

Comment: その辺りの情報は質問に追記したほうがよいでしょう。質問見ただけでそこまでは分からないので。Jupyter-server, nbconvert に関しては, どこに・どの様にインストールしたかの情報も(`user` スキームかどうかとか)。あと, 普通に `python3 -m jupyter nbconvert --version` でエラー出るかどうかも (vs code の連携の問題なのか, nbconvert がそもそも動かないのか, 確認のため)